# Condition and applying formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables.

**Table 1**

```
CREATE TABLE ##MedianTemp1 (
  ProductID INT  NOT NULL,
  CountryCodeID INT NOT NULL,
  Y1977 INT NULL,
  Y1978 INT NULL,
  Y1979 INT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ProductID,CountryCodeID))

INSERT INTO ##MedianTemp1 VALUES 
(1, 100, 0, 0, 0),
(2, 100, 0, 0, 0),
(3, 100, 0, 0, 0),
(4, 100, 0, 0, 0),
(5, 100, 1, 0, 0),
(6, 100, 1, 1, 0),
(7, 100, 1, 1, 1),
(8, 100, 1, 1, 1),
(9, 100, 1, 1, 1),
(1, 101, 0, 0, 0),
(2, 101, 0, 0, 0),
(3, 101, 0, 0, 0),
(4, 101, 1, 0, 0),
(5, 101, 1, 1, 0),
(6, 101, 1, 1, 1),
(7, 101, 1, 1, 1),
(8, 101, 1, 1, 1),
(9, 101, 1, 1, 1)
```

**Table 2**

```
CREATE TABLE    ##MedianTemp2 (
  ProductID INT  NOT NULL, 
  CountryCodeID INT NOT NULL,
  Y1977 FLOAT(53) NULL, 
  Y1978 FLOAT(53) NULL, 
  Y1979 FLOAT(53) NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ProductID,CountryCodeID))

INSERT INTO ##MedianTemp2 VALUES 
(1, 100, 5, 4, 1),
(2, 100, 6, 3, 2),
(3, 100, 1, 2, 4),
(4, 100, 2, 1, 5),
(5, 100, 6, 2, 6),
(6, 100, 7, 3, 7),
(7, 100, 1, 2, 3),
(8, 100, 7, 1, 8),
(9, 100, 9, 6, 9),
(1, 101, 5, 4, 1),
(2, 101, 6, 3, 2),
(3, 101, 1, 2, 4),
(4, 101, 2, 1, 5),
(5, 101, 6, 2, 6),
(6, 101, 7, 3, 7),
(7, 101, 1, 2, 3),
(8, 101, 7, 1, 8),
(9, 101, 9, 6, 9)
```

I need to create this:

```
##MedianResult (
  ProductID INT  NOT NULL,
  CountryCodeID INT NOT NULL,
  Y1977 FLOAT(53) NULL,
  Y1978 FLOAT(53) NULL,
  Y1979 FLOAT(53) NULL
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ProductID,CountryCodeID))
```

Query should find the only one `ProductID` for each year and for each CountryID (from `##medianTemp1` table) which will have value `'0'` and `ProductID+1` will have `1`.

For this founded `productID` (for yeach year and for each country it will be different) we should apply a formula using values from `##MedianTemp2` table. `Sum(ProductID, ProductID+1, ProductID+2)`.

I know that my description is a bit weird ... but don't know how to describe my problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE #mt1
GO
-- first you need to bring your table to a usable format:
select 
    productid, countrycodeid,
    val, yr
into #mt1
from ##MedianTemp1
unpivot (
    val for yr in (y1977, y1978, y1979)
) y


-- and here to find the products
select 
    a.*
    ,b.*
from #mt1 a
join #mt1 b
    on a.productid+1=b.productid
    and a.countrycodeid=b.countrycodeid
    and a.yr=b.yr
where 1=1
    and a.val=0
    and b.val=1
```

To make final calculation, use above methods again, that is:

- unpivot the table ##MedianTemp2
- apply a join two times on productid+1 and productid+2 to sum the values

I think you'll figure this out. +1 for F5-sample :).

Comment: Working prety cool! thanks
Just one question why do we need 1=1  in where clause?